# Pagination problem after WP_Query with tag filtering

Tags: wp-query, pagination, tags

I have a problem with a custom WP_Query. I want a page with all posts with a specific tag. This is the code I'm using:

```
<?php 
//save old query
$temp = $wp_query; 
//clear $wp_query; 
$wp_query= null; 
 ?>      
<?php 
// The Query
$wp_query = new WP_Query();
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array( 'tag' => 'concurs', 'paged' => $paged );
$wp_query->query($args);
?>
<?php 
// The Loop
while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) :
    $wp_query->the_post();
 ?>  
[some code that displays the title, excerpt, meta-info (author, category, date) and thumbnail] 
      <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php posts_nav_link(); ?>              
<?php 
//clear again
$wp_query = null; 
//reset
$wp_query = $temp;  
 ?>
```

The problem is that when I switch to page 2 or 3 I get the same 10 first posts. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you considered using the `pre_get_posts` filter to modify the main query instead? It would be significantly faster, an the code would be much smaller/simpler than discarding the main query and reinventing it, doubling the work and page load in the process

Comment: You're right, at that moment my WordPress knowledge was limited, now I know I should have used the `pre_get_posts` filter. Go ahead an post an answer and I'll mark it as correct, hopefully it will help others to not make the same mistake as I have.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I've figured out the correct coding for this problem:

```
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$wp_query = new WP_Query();
$wp_query->query('tag=concurs&posts_per_page='.get_option('posts_per_page').'&paged=' . $paged);
?>
<?php if ($wp_query->have_posts()) : ?>
    <?php while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>  
[code for title, author, category, meta-info etc] 
<?php endwhile; ?>
 <div class="next-prev"><?php posts_nav_link( ' ', '<img src="' . get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/img/pagina-precedenta.png" align="left" />', '<img src="' . get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/img/pagina-urmatoare.png" align="right" />'); ?></div>  
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Your query has no [paging](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters).

You need to tell the query what page your on so it can get the right results for you.  You can grab the 'paged' query_var for this.

Comment: Thanks, I've included the `paged` query_var in the code but it's still not working [code updated above].